# Need a way to make HttpClient in c# work like axios in nodejs (with proxies)

Tags: c#, node.js, axios, webclient, https-proxy-agent

When im using axios into nodejs and set the httpAgent with a new instance of httpProxyAgent, it works well in nodejs and i dont get the cloudflare warning.

```
module.exports.GetClient = (proxy = null) => {
const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0",
}

const client = axios.create({
    headers,
    httpsAgent: new HttpsProxyAgent(module.exports.ParseProxy(proxy), { keepAlive: true }),
    httpAgent: new HttpProxyAgent(module.exports.ParseProxy(proxy), { keepAlive: true }),
})

return client;
}
```

When im using c# RestSharp or WebClient, i cant find a way to reproduce the same working system as axios with httpProxyAgent.
Somebody can help me with that?

Comment: The `Proxy` is set by the HttpClient handler. Use a [SocketsHttpHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler) in this case

Comment: It works but still it doesnt bypass the cloudflare like axios and http-proxy-agent does